# Get top voted results from wordpress database structure

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My video posts are saving in WordPress `wp_posts` table along with the video details in `wp_postmeta` table.

The structure of `wp_posts` table is like this:

```
-------------------------------
ID  |  post_title  |  post_type
-------------------------------
1   |  Video 1     |  my-videos
2   |  Video 2     |  my-videos
3   |  Video 3     |  my-videos
-------------------------------
```

and the structure of `wp_postmeta` table is like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
meta_id  |  post_id  |  meta_key  |  meta_value
-----------------------------------------------
1        |  1        |  vote      |  98
2        |  1        |  category  |  9
3        |  2        |  vote      |  101
4        |  2        |  category  |  9
5        |  3        |  vote      |  657
6        |  3        |  category  |  15
```

My desired result should be:

```
----------
Category 9
----------
Video 2
Video 1
```

But I'm not be able to achieve this ... My query is like this:

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'my-videos' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'vote' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'category' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 9 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC`

Its definately something wrong with my query. Would really appreciate if someone can direct me to correct path :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT
    post.post_title as 'Category 9'
FROM
    wp_postmeta pmc
    JOIN wp_postmeta pmv
        ON pmv.post_id = pmc.post_id
    JOIN wp_posts post
        ON pmc.post_id = post.ID
        AND post.post_type = 'my-videos'
WHERE
    pmc.meta_key = 'category'
    AND pmc.meta_value = 9
GROUP BY
    post.post_title
ORDER BY
    pmv.meta_value DESC
```

Not sure how big your tables are, but it seems like joining on the meta table twice is the most performant solution. (Especially if it's indexed.)

Comment: Both answers @tcadidot0's and Yours are working ... but yours is less complex. Will try to implement in my code now.

Comment: I agree @Omer .. In my answer, I was wondering a few things while writing it. One of it is how Jason point out about the meta attribute "What if its more than just `category` & `vote`?" my query suggestion will fail for sure... and that's regarding on one column only :)

Comment: @tcadidot0 you are right ... I tried it ... I have more than `category` & `vote` meta attributes. Will your query work if I have more than 8 meta attributes?

Comment: @Omer FWIW: it could still work-- you'd just need to add an additional WHERE statement to filter down to those two keys. The bigger problem, I think, is the performance of doing a GROUP_CONCAT and then a SUBSTRING_INDEX. You have to build a string and then parse it for each value. The operations themselves are a bit slow, and you won't be able to take advantage of any indexes on those columns.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think the `wp_postmeta` table seem a bit strange for not having a column for each of the `meta_key` but anyway, I can suggest using a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions. Below is the example query:

```
SELECT id, 
       post_title, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(mval,',',1) AS "Category",
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(mval,',',-1) AS "Votes"
FROM
(SELECT    wp_posts.id, 
           wp_posts.post_title,
           wp_posts.post_type,
           GROUP_CONCAT(meta_key ORDER BY meta_key) AS "mkey", 
           GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY meta_key) AS "mval"
 FROM      wp_posts 
 LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
 ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id GROUP BY wp_posts.id) A
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(mval,',',1)='9'
ORDER BY Votes ASC;
```

And here is the fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qniBEo4MgrExvekmCnSPRG/2

There are two working queries here:

1. The sub-query I use `GROUP_CONCAT` on `meta_value` column.
2. The outer query I use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` on `mval` to fetch the category and value.

**P/S: This will only work if `meta_key` is two only or if coincidentally the `meta_key` values you want are ordered in correct position.**

Comment: "I personally think the wp_postmeta table seem a bit strange for not having a column for each of the meta_key... " Maybe. But, the way it is, you don't have to add a new column every time you want a new meta attribute. I think there's some value in that. IMO, though, it would be good to normalize the `meta_key`'s so you don't have to do string compares when you query the table. :)

Comment: You're correct about that. I was thinking that the `meta_key`have two types only.. category & vote .. it didn't occur to me that it might be more .. xD

Comment: Guys the `meta_keys` can be unlimited (well not unlimited obviously, I just need 9 of them) :/